# Using a Catalyst model in a non-Catalyst setting

Tags: perl, model, catalyst

What is the correct way to get a Catalyst model output (for some specific model) from a Perl script? I mean a standalone Perl script, for example a script starting from command line.

What is the correct way to do this? Please provide an example.

Comment: Please show what you tried. Don't know if it's possible at all.

Comment: Backwards. The model should use re-usable libraries

Comment: You can write a controller that calls what you want on your model and make a CGI PSGI wrapper that you can call from the command line. Or you can create an instance of your app in a regular Perl script and grab the model. Catalyst's unit test tools should be helpful for that. It's all a bit complicated though. But if you want the model to magically know all its settings and it might even have `ACCEPT_CONTEXT` defined then you cannot just instantiate one yourself. Unless you don't need anything but e.g. database config. Then you can just `use` it, instantiate it and be done.

Comment: It's probably too late for this, but this is the reason why it's always encouraged to write very thin models that simply provide the glue between Catalyst and a non-Catalyst module. That way, when you want to use the model outside Catalyst, you simply use that module, and nothing is lost. Any code that you put directly into a model requires a Catalyst app, a Catalyst config, and possibly a Catalyst request context, to run properly.